# SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 0): Method call: Method hasPermission(java.lang.String) cannot be found on MethodSecurityExpressionRoot type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I add to my project a class CustomPermissionEvaluator, configured by a configuration class MethodSecurityConfig, but when I try run my application, after I inform my login credencials, I am receiving this error message:

```
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/webapp2] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'hasPermission('admin_main')'] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 0): Method call: Method hasPermission(java.lang.String) cannot be found on org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot type
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:202)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:118)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:80)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.before(ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:24)
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.acesso.controller.PrivadoController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e6bb4ae6_2.admin(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My class CustomPermissionEvaluator is that:

```
@Component
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    public CustomPermissionEvaluator() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        System.out.println("CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission");
        if (arg0 == null || !arg0.isAuthenticated())
            return false;
        else
            return arg0.getAuthorities().contains(arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Serializable arg1, String arg2, Object arg3) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Id-based permission evaluation not currently supported.");
    }

}
```

My configuration class MethodSecurityConfig is that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        System.out.println("MethodSecurityConfig.createExpressionHandler");
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }

}
```

Full code of my security layer can be found here:

https://github.com/klebermo/webapp2/tree/master/src/com/spring/webapp/lojavirtual/config/security

Anyone can point what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I use the annotation @PreAuthorize in this way:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="privado")
public class PrivadoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('admin_main')")
    public ModelAndView admin() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("privado/admin");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="customer")
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('customer_main')")
    public ModelAndView customer() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("privado/customer");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, finally I get to work done this part of my project. The final code for the CustomPermissionEvaluator is:

```
@Component
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    public CustomPermissionEvaluator() {
    }

    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Object arg1) {
        System.out.println("CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission");
        System.out.println("arg0 = "+arg0);
        System.out.println("arg1 = "+arg1);

        if (arg0 == null || !arg0.isAuthenticated()) {
            System.out.println("false");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("true");
            for(GrantedAuthority authority: arg0.getAuthorities()) {
                if(authority.getAuthority().equals(arg1))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        System.out.println("CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission");
        System.out.println("arg0 = "+arg0);
        System.out.println("arg1 = "+arg1);
        System.out.println("arg2 = "+arg2);

        if (arg0 == null || !arg0.isAuthenticated()) {
            System.out.println("false");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("true");
            for(GrantedAuthority authority: arg0.getAuthorities()) {
                if(authority.getAuthority().equals(arg2))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Serializable arg1, String arg2, Object arg3) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Id-based permission evaluation not currently supported.");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error as you. Even I added `hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Object arg1)` method but it still doesn't work. Do you have any way?

Comment: resolved my issue with above code

Answer (score 1):

Then I solve the problem presented here changing the call for hasPermission in the methods from my controller. The final code for them are:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="privado")
public class PrivadoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#usuario, 'admin_main')")
    public ModelAndView admin() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("privado/admin");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="customer")
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#usuario, 'customer_main')")
    public ModelAndView customer() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("privado/customer");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

(Now I am trying find the correct argument for replace #usuario, which is returning a null value, but this is subject for another topic).

Answer (score 0):

```
... Method hasPermission(java.lang.String) cannot be found ...
```

The method `hasPermission()` is called at any time with only one argument, but you provide it with 3 and 4 arguments:

```
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Serializable arg1, String arg2, Object arg3)
```

Add the method `public boolean hasPermission(String permission)` and try again.

Comment: I add to the topic the code where I use the hasPermission method. How I should complement the method call to match the implementations I have? Or, if I add a method with 1 argument, how I could get the list of authorities from logged user? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code where you use `hasPermission('admin_main')`.

Although it is wrong anyway: your `CustomPermissionEvaluator` doesn't have a method with single argument. Or in terms of Spring Security like this:

```
boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object permission);
```

Maybe do you want to use `hasRole('admin_main')` ?..

The main your problem that you don't provide enough arguments for method implementations.

Comment: I was one second faster :-P

Comment: I add to the topic the code where I use the hasPermission method. How I should complement the method call to match the implementations I have? Or, if I add a method with 1 argument, how I could get the list of authorities from logged user? Any thoughts?