# SpEL - Error: Method cannot be found on type

Tags: java, spring, caching, annotations, spring-el

I am running into a problem while trying to implement a spring cache.

I only can provide a schematic snippet (posting real code would probably get me fired :S)

```
public class CacheTestServiceImpl {

    @Cacheable(value=SOME_STRING_CONSTANT, key="#root.targetClass.createHashCode(#root.args[0])")
    public int getID(String userName, String someOtherParam) {
    } 

    public int createHashCode(String userName) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and the error i keep getting is `EL1004E:(pos 18): Method createHashCode(String) cannot be found on CacheTestServiceImpl type.`

Any suggestions on what i might be doing wrong? if you need any further information, i'd be glad to provide it ofc :)
thanks

EDIT: i just had the "brilliant" idea of searching for the error code itself and dug up this: [relevant stack-oerflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154239/spelevaluationexception-el1004epos-0-method-call-method-haspermissionjava)

so i will check it out and keep this question updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to invoke a **static** method createHashCode, yet your class does not declare any. So, either make your method static or use `#root.target.createHashCode(#root.args[0])` SpEL expression.

Refer to [Spring Cache abstraction reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-spel-context) for more info

Comment: this made the error disappear, so based on the infos i am able to give here -> great answer :) due to our architecture i think i will change the whole structure and give the parameter classes hashCode()/equals() overrides and use the "default key generation" that spring apparently offers here (just found that out)..

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 potential problems.

1. createHashCode is private
2. createHashCode is static. There is a particular spel syntax to call static methods : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html#d0e11977

Comment: i changed it to "public" only, still the same error. thanks for the 2nd hint though! cant hurt to know that